# I’m looking for name and rules of a solitaire game my Grandma taught me, but don’t remember

Tags: solitaire

The solitaire game is set up in a square four cards top and sides(looks more like a rectangle).  A pile of cards is place in the middle.  I’m not sure of how many, I think it was ten.

You play on piles to the left of the square using the cards in the square and rest of the deck.  As the corners are used you pull from the middle pile to replace them.

Sorry, I haven’t played this game for 40+ years.